# How to get key value pair from appSettings into a collection of SelectListItem?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, appsettings

```
 <add key="Domain1" value="GREAT"/>
<add key="Domain2" value="NA"/>
<add key="Domain3" value="NZDOM"/>

   IEnumerable<SelectListItem> domainItems = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys
                             .Where(key => key.StartsWith("Domain"))
                             .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                             {
                                 Value = "???", //Want the key not a collection
                                 Text = "???" //Want the value not a collection
                             });
```

I guess the problem is with the Allkeys object? And so the select is acting how I imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `x` is the key, so you just need to use `x` itself and `Get` to get the value:

```
{
    Value = x,
    Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(x)
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Its just a list of Keys which are the strings. I am so used to dealing with objects that using simple strings throws me off